# Android: Button onclick showing error

Tags: android, onclick

For my two buttons I want to implement a switch case and with on click I am getting the following errors how to solve this?

> void is an invalid type for the
>   variable onClick 
>              Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

Here is my code.

```
        Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
        Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);

    String gender; 
    gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
  public void onClick(View v) {

      switch(v.getId()){

      case R.id.regmalebtn:
    //    String gender; 
    //    gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
        gender.equals("M");
    //  request.addProperty("gender",gender );

           break;

      case R.id.regfemalebtn:
          gender = regfemalebtn.getText().toString();
            gender.equals("F");
            //request.addProperty("gender", gender);
           break;
           default:
               break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: In which line you are getting this error?

Comment: first start with some basic android examples

Comment: @user618541  in the line  public void onClick(View v) I am getting the error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting the following error

Syntax error on token ")", ; expected

```
That means onClick() method is defined inside another method. It should be defined outside of any method in the same class
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks,   I declared outside the method but now its showing Syntax error on token ";", , expected  on the line      Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);

Answer (score 1):

Please remove
    default:
                   break;

from case R.id.regfemalebtn:

And code must looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

      switch(v.getId()){

      case R.id.regmalebtn:
    //    String gender; 
    //    gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
        gender.equals("M");
    //  request.addProperty("gender",gender );

           break;

      case R.id.regfemalebtn:
          gender = regfemalebtn.getText().toString();
            gender.equals("F");
            //request.addProperty("gender", gender);
           break;
      }
default:
               break;
  }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks,but This not the correct answer ,see the errors which I posted above

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class Sample extends Activity implements OnClickListener
   {
      public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           super.onCreate(bundle);
           setContentView(//ur layout);
           Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn);
           Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
           regmalebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
           regfemalebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
           String gender; 
           gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
       }//onCreate()
       public void onClick(View v) {
          switch(v.getId()){
               case R.id.regmalebtn:
                       //String gender; 
                       //    gender = regmalebtn.getText().toString();
                       gender.equals("M");
                        //  request.addProperty("gender",gender );
                      break;
               case R.id.regfemalebtn:
                       gender = regfemalebtn.getText().toString();
                       gender.equals("F");
                       //request.addProperty("gender", gender);
                      break;
               default:
                      break;
      }//onclick()
 }//Sample
```

Try this code..

Comment: Thanks, I did the same wat u said still its showing Syntax error on token ";", , expected on the line Button regfemalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn)